# Conditional Split in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, conditional-statements

I have two columns one is Emp_id(Not null) & other is Emp_email(Null Allowable).I want to transfer only those

records of employes in which Emp_email is present.How can i archive this is SSIS..?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 4):

You can just implement this using the following logic.

First you check for Non-null columns, and then (if you want), don't include those where email address is empty. You need the ISNULL first because you cannot evaluate a column that is NULL to a value, it'll result in a NULL value which cannot be represented in a boolean fashion (True/False). With the following logic the Emp_Email != "" will never be evaluated if it is NULL.

[image: SSIS Conditional Split Editor]

Answer (score 2):

Just do this in your OLE DB Source: Add a `WHERE ISNULL(Emp_email, '') <> ''` to your SQL statement and you should be done.

Comment: i want the above thing in SSIS not in Sql server

Comment: I think it must be very easy in SSIS<plz help me out

Comment: You write that SQL statement in SSIS, not in SQL Server. I asume you have an OLE DB Source in your Data Flow. Other wise we need more information!

Answer (score 1):

just drag the green arrow from your source into the conditional split and build your expression like `!ISNULL(Emp_email)`. That will be your condition 1 (emails are not null). When you drag the green arrow from the conditional split to the destination, it will ask you which condition do you want that flow to be, then you select 1.